# iOS 6 using different autorotation in parent and child ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I am little stuck here.

I use a NavigationController to show different ViewControllers each having its own autorotation settings. As others here on stack overflow suggested I subclassed UINavigationController and implemented

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIViewController *top = [self topViewController];
    return [top shouldAutorotate];  
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;   
}
```

In my ViewControllers I then set the desired behavior. This works fine so far.

However in one scenario I want to have content which should not rotate together with rotating elements. The idea is to show in full screen (hiding the status bar) images of the device's camera with some 3D content rendered on top (using the Vuforia framework) which is shown in portrait orientation only. To allow for adjustments I also want to use a toolbar to optionally show different adjustment views. This I intend to use on top of the  3D view and being able to rotate according to the device's orientation.

To achieve this I tried to use two ViewController. One for the toolbar and the adjustment views embedded as a child ViewController in the ViewController for the 3D view.
For this I adopted the code example below taken from Apple [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];                 
    content.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          
}
```

Unfortunately with this approach the toolbar won't rotate. Only in the parent ViewController shouldAutorotate gets called, which seems logical as the child will not be the topViewController. But then again in both controllers there is a call to supportedInterfaceOrientations.
I also tried to embed both controllers as children in a third controller, with the same result.

Another idea was to rotate the toolbar manually, but because the parent returns NO for shouldAutorotate I didn't find a simple way to detect rotations, as the rotation handling methods then don't get called.

What I did before and what actually worked, was to allow for rotation and manually rotating back the 3D view. But the effect was not very appealing.

What could I do to have rotating and fixed content at the same time?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to create new `UIWindow` and add your fullscreen ViewController to it's `rootViewController`. Than you can customise you rotation behaviour for  your own `UIWindow`(and it's ViewControllers) as you need.

Comment: Great - I was not aware that it is possible to use multiple windows. UIWindow reference states that there are three possible windowLevels, UIWindowLevelNormal, UIWindowLevelStatusBar and UIWindowLevelAlert with respective values of 0.0, 1000.0 and 2000.0 To have the right order I set an individual windowLevel for the window containing the toolbar keeping it on top of the 3D view but below the statusbar and alert levels. This works, but is this the correct way?